# Sort result alphabetically in linq to sql

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting

I am using `linq` to `sql` to get results from a database. I want to sort these results alphabetically:

```
dim result = (from c in db.table order by c.name ascending select c).tolist
```

This sorts first by capitalized words, and then by lower case words. For example:

> FALL
>   ZOO
>   football
>   lion

The result I'm looking for is:

> FALL
>   football
>   lion
>   ZOO

How do I fix my code to do that?

Comment: I believe you will need to specify `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` in your `orderby` clause. As in `(from c in db.table).OrderBy(Function(x) x.name, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToList()`. This requires using the lambda variant of `OrderBy`.

Comment: Is `db` an Entity Framework model?

Comment: yes db is object of Entity Framework mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting result first all from capital then from small case. But converting it to lower, I got accurate results

```
dim result = (from c in db.table order by c.name.tolwer ascending select c).tolist
```